# Remove white space in html5 input date

Tags: html, input

How to remove the whitespace in input type date field?

Below is the code

```
<input id="min_expiry_date" disabled="disabled" type="date" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}">
```

And below is how it appears on the chrome and edge browser

[image]

How do i remove the whitespace that appears after yyyy-mm-dd?
Tried applying min-width and white-space no-wrap, padding and margin 0. Negative margin works but not the  intended way.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
width: auto 
border-block: none;
```

will do that, It will be a dynamic size input box

**Edited**

```
<div class ="exp">
<input id="min_expiry_date" disabled="disabled" type="date" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" >
</div>
```

**css**

```
.exp input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't remove that white space after the string "yyyy-mm-dd". Is that a bug by any chance?

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Had no idea about that pseudo selector.
Its better now, but still leaves little space. Is it possible to zero down the margin and padding or anything that is occupying space there.